# ASSIMP aiNode->mMeshes understanding

Tags: opengl, skeletal-animation, assimp

I'm trying to use ASSIMP to load an fbx file with a skeleton and animations, but I'm stuck on something I'm misunderstanding and struggling to see it.

I've attached 2 images, one of the fbx file as rendered by Open 3D Mod which uses ASSIMP and looks correct. The second image is my renderer that does not look correct. The only thing wrong with mine is that the main body is rotated 90 degrees from what it should be.

For this fbx file, it has 3 nodes that contain a mesh to draw: "Mesh 1" is the main body and "Mesh 0" is an axe. The axe is referenced twice, once from each hand node. The main body mesh's vertices are tied to the bones, so Mesh 1 gets animated with the bones. The axe mesh's vertices are not tied to bones.

So I'm traversing the skeleton, and when I get to a node that references a mesh to draw, I transform to that node's position, then draw the mesh instance at that spot. This is how the axe meshes get animated: the axe mesh vertices are not tied to bones, but since the hand nodes reference them, I transform wherever the hand bone animation currently is then draw them.

My problem is when I do this same thing on the main body (Mesh 1), it ends up rotated 90 degrees as seen in the blue picture. The reason is because the node it is attached to has an mTransformation of -90 degrees about the x-axis.

Another note is that the mTransformation of the RootNode is the identity matrix, so the global inverse is identity.

There's too much code involved for me to realistically be able to post it here. However, the relevant logic follows what's shown in this tutorial: http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk/www/tutorial38/tutorial38.html
The one thing the tutorial doesn't mention is handling the mesh references at each node. If I ignore where the meshes are referenced from, the body works but the axes break (axes don't animate any more and simply draw at their bind position).

The model I'm using was a free one I grabbed from the unity store for testing:
https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/3d/animations/zombie-0-1-19254

My questions are:
Am I correctly interpreting the mesh references at a node by transforming to the node position prior to drawing?
If so, why does this get the axes to the correct place but not the main body?
If not, what am I missing?

[[image] Open 3D Mod's render, looking down the Z axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AWPrG.png)
[[image] My render, looking down the Z axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ac00G.png)

Comment: See related [ASSIMP bug report](https://github.com/assimp/assimp/issues/849). Typically, there are export options available for adjusting axes & orientation. Have you looked into those? What 3D asset creation tool was used to create it? Blender, Max, Maya...?

Comment: Not sure what tool created it, this is an example model I pulled some time ago, can't remember from where. When I have time, I'll look at opening it in some of those tools to see if there's anything weird going on with the axes. Not sure why the pick axes would be in the correct spot if that is the issue, but I'll take a look and see. Thanks for the ideas, will reply once I have a chance to look tomorrow. Edited my question with a link to the model if you're interested in looking at it

Comment: @ArcaneEngineer, pulled the model up in unity editor, verified the axes are correct. Unity draws the model correctly, so I played around with it and noticed that unity ignores the -90 degree transform at that node. No matter what I change that node's transform to, unity draws it the same. Not true for the pick axe nodes, if I modify those transforms, unity moves them around. Is there some metadata somewhere or something that says not to use the node's transform?

Comment: OK, at least that's some progress. That does sound weird. This is probably a hack attempt, but I'd pull that model into Blender and re-export it without changes, or else examine it therein to see if there is anything dodgy going on with the body. (Don't forget there is more orientation stuff to fiddle with on re-export.) The other thing I'd try to do is create a simple body myself, of course rigging is not for the faint-hearted if you've never done it. Then see the difference between the two. Not elegant, but possibly effective.

Comment: Oh and remember that you can change and _apply_ transformations to the vertices in 3D asset creation tools like Blender. Maybe you could give it +90, try import that, then give it -90 again, try import that? See if these  changes can alone fix the model on re-export. Also, if you export this model to some text-based format like Collada(?), perhaps you can find out more. Lastly, trying a different humanoid model could be informative, assuming the node/bone layout is not hugely different.

Comment: Blender throws an error and won't import the fbx file. Used open3mod to export to collada then import to blender, but lost the animations somehow. Then exported from blender back to fbx. That fbx file draws with correct orientation for me. Also played with the -90 degree transform manually in the collada file and noticed both blender and open3mod do use that transform, unlike unity. So confusing. Think I'm getting closer but not quite there yet.

Comment: Is that a root level transform? Is it possible Unity ignores empty root objects? I have seen model hierarchies in the past where there are multiple empty nodes before we get to the actual "good stuff". Maybe Unity thinks that node is a crock?

Comment: Started logging lots of debug to a file during the fbx load in my code. Ran it against the original fbx file (that draws on it's back) and the fbx file I exported to dae then back to fbx (which draws standing up correctly but has no animations). Found that the original fbx file's node with the -90 degree rotation has a metadata key for RotationActive that's set to true while the working one does not. FBX doc says this is for rotation min/max limits, which I don't have keys for and the defaults for both are zero. My interpretation is it means I'm supposed to ignore the rotation on this node?

Comment: That can't be correct, that just sounds dumb. Why give a node a rotation and limit it to not be used instead of just not giving the node a rotation???